# NullPointerException

Tags: blackberry

I am building an app but on running my code i keep getting a nullpointer exception when i debug it i dont seem to notice what could possibly be giving it an error,i get it on the coated line , do i need to put the class of this method for a better explanation ?
Thanks

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) { 
     graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
     graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
  // graphics.drawBitmap(xInt, yInt, imgWidth, imgHeight, _currentPicture, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.  Also, please provide the **actual** error message.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing on that line that I can see that would be causing a NullPointerException would be if `_currentPicture` were `null`. You could test the theory by changing your code to:

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    if(_currentPicture != null) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics
            .drawBitMap(xInt, yInt, imgWidth, imgHeight, _currentPicture, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah that got it working thanks but then again  the pictures not showing?

Comment: @Jide - The picture isn't showing because you haven't initialized anything into the _currentPicture variable. That's why it is null.

Answer (score 0):

The variable _currentPicture isn't initialized. Look farther back in your code and see where it gets set. We can't do much more without more code or the full stacktrace.

Comment: Ok, so I don't see your class, but from what the person below me posted, it still didn't quite fix it for you. If you could try posting the class again, I might have something to work with. Until then, all I can say is it looks like _currentPicture needs to be set somewhere and that isn't quite happening.

Comment: class MyCustomImgButton extends Field implements DrawStyle{    
 private Bitmap _currentPicture;  
      
    private int width;  
    private int height; 
    MyCustomImgButton thisButton;
    MyCustomImgButton (String onImage, String offImage, int fWidth, int fHeight, int iWidth, int iHeight, int x, int y){
            super();
            
            _onPicture =Bitmap.getBitmapResource(onImage);//, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            _offPicture = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(offImage);//, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            _currentPicture = _offPicture;

Comment: i am new to this so apologies for the way my class is....i do not know how to upload the whole class,i only hope that helps??

Comment: Is the file you're trying to access in your res folder?

Comment: i got the code from this website http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/12/user-defined-buttons-create-custom.html                                                    it was working before i dont know why it stopped ...... its not a file i have to access from res folder i think its just a reference to the images copied into the res folder?